# Photoshop Gradient selection in Quick Mask Mode not working properly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, gradient, selections

When I make a selection in quick mask mode using the gradient tool (black to white) the equivalent selection is not from 0% to 100% but actually from 0% to around 99%.

So lets say, on a new layer, I draw a blue circle, then go into Quick Mask Mode, select the gradient tool, reset swatches and draw a horizontal gradient from the circle centre to the edge of the circle, click out of QMM (to effect the marching ants selection) and then 'Make new layer from selection', that new layer's bounds are not half the circle but the whole circle?! On close inspection the other half of the circle is still there just at one percent opacity.

Any one know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having difficulty replicating the issue. It seems to work as expected. [See example](https://imgur.com/tjDSHfV). Sorry about that. Can you perhaps share a screen shot demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Is this link helpful? https://imgur.com/a/yJbJlNh

Comment: Your link shows exactly the same steps I tried. But I still can't replicate the problem. Maybe reach out to Adobe customer support. Perhaps you've discovered a bug?

Comment: I've watched your video. Only thing I can imagine is that the gradient isn't actually going from black to white. Your video just shows you selecting gradient and resetting fore- and background color to black and white. Photoshop remembers previously used gradients. You probably checked this already.

Comment: Thats exactly the root of my issue: If I'm selecting the Default Swatches button while in Quick Mask Mode, the values should be pure black to pure white (ie: 0% to 100%). Or am I missing something?